# Match Each Occurrence of '.' Except Last

Tags: regex, sed

Input data (filenames):

```
Word1.Word2 Word3.ext
Word1.Word2 Word3.Word4.ext
Word1 Word2.Word2.ext
Word1 Word2.Word3 Word4.ext
```

where `.ext` varies according to file type and the words are delimited by a space or '.'

Desired output:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4.ext
```

I know I can replace every occurrence of '.':

```
s/\\./ /
```

and I know I can get the last . with the extension:

```
(.[^\\.]*)$
```

but I can't figure-out how to join it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that doesn't rely on extended regular expressions, just stock `sed`:

```
sed 'h;s/.*\(\.[^.]*\)/\1/;x;s/\.[^.]*$//;s/\./ /g;G;s/\n//'
```

Commands are separated by semicolons and do this:

- `h` copies the line to the hold space, preserving the original text while we work,
- `s` removes everything except the last dot and extension, and there's no need for a dollar sign in the regular expression because `.*` is greedy enough to take as much of the line as it can,
- `x` swaps this dot-and-extension with the original line that we saved in the hold space,
- `s` removes the last dot and extension from the original line,
- `s` replaces every remaining dot with a space (and the `g` modifier means replace all of them, not just the first),
- `G` appends the dot-and-extension that we saved in the hold space onto the dotless line (but separating them with a newline),
- and `s` removes that annoying newline.

---

One note about your original post: your regex for the period and extension, which you show as

```
(.[^\\.]*)$
```

should be

```
\.[^.]*$
```

Outside of the square brackets, a period matches any character, so if you want to match a period you need to escape it with a backslash. But inside the square brackets, it only matches a period. And you can drop the parens unless you're trying to capture the matched string.

Comment: Thank you.  That's perfect for me.  Thanks for the note about the [] also.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do it using `perl` lookahead regex:

```
perl -pe 's/\.(?=.*\.[^.]*$)/ $1/g' file

Word1 Word2 Word3.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3.Word4.ext
Word1 Word2 Word2.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4.ext
```

Or else use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F '.' '{$(NF-1) = $(NF-1) "." $NF; NF--} 1' file

Word1 Word2 Word3.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4.ext
Word1 Word2 Word2.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4.ext
```

If you have to use `sed` only then use:

```
sed ':a
s/\.\([^.]*\.\)/ \1/g
ta' file

Word1 Word2 Word3.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4.ext
Word1 Word2 Word2.ext
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4.ext
```

Comment: Wow! That was quick.  Thank you.  I don't know if I am keying something wrong, but I still get some odd dots in 2nd and 4th rows: Word1 Word2 Word3.Word4 ext and Word1 Word2.Word3 Word4.ext

Comment: Thanks.  I am sure they work, but I was really looking for a sed solution if possible.  (I am trying to get the hang of the regex part really!)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I found the non-extended version worked best for me.

Comment: Removing `-E` is fairly straight forward as you can see in edited answer. I am really puzzled why this simple sed doesn't work for you than the long complicated sed you chose.

Answer (score 0):

The RE below finds:

- Find .
- anything but dot.
- find . again
- anything but dot.
- EOL

```
\.([^\\.]*\.[^\\.]*)$
```

Group everything but the leading "."
Then replace with " $1"